# Bash script in VMware Check for 2 different inputs

Tags: bash, vmware-esxi

I need to ask for a second arguement for NFS. I have the vswitches labeled NFS. I am already asking for the IP but now I need to ask for the switch an example is NFS01, NFS02. I need a little help with the logic. I am very new to bash so please talk slow and try not to be cryptic.

```
#!/bin/ash -v



E_NOARGS=65

if [[ -z "$1" ]]
then
echo "Usage: ./`basename $0` [IP_Address]"
exit $E_NOARGS
fi

esxcfg-vswitch -m 9000 vSwitch2
esxcfg-vswitch -l
esxcfg-nics -l
sleep 15
esxcfg-vswitch -A NFS vSwitch2
sleep 10
esxcfg-vswitch -p NFS -v 20 vSwitch2
sleep 10
esxcfg-vmknic -a -i "$1" -n 255.255.255.0 -m 9000 NFS
sleep 10
vmkping -s 9000 192.168.9.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I really understand what you're asking, but something like the following might work for you...

```
if [ $# != 2 ]; then
  echo "Usage: ./`basename $0` [IP_Address] [switch]"
  exit $E_NOARGS
fi
```

Then use $2 wherever you need to specify the switch value.

Comment: Can you look below and tell me if this is what your talking about

Comment: Is this what your say to do? I just want to verify before I run it on a production system. #!/bin/ash -v E_NOARGS=65 if [ $# != 2 ]; then echo "Usage: ./`basename $0` [IP_Address] [switch]" exit $E_NOARGS fi esxcfg-vswitch -m 9000 vSwitch2 esxcfg-vswitch -l esxcfg-nics -l sleep 15 esxcfg-vswitch -A "$2" vSwitch2 sleep 10 esxcfg-vswitch -p "$2" -v 20 vSwitch2 sleep 10 esxcfg-vmknic -a -i "$1" -n 255.255.255.0 -m 9000 "$2" sleep 10 vmkping -s 9000 192.168.9.3

Comment: @randy I would never suggest deploying a change to a production system without testing it offline first, but it appears that you have correctly interpreted my suggestion.